# Ubuntu16.04LTS terminal doesn't open

Tags: command-line

I have encountered a weird problem, terminal cannot be opened in Applications>>search terminal. But i can open terminal in file folder by right click and select "open in terminal". Any ideas? I'm completely new to Ubuntu, thanks in advance.